# React Router - how to load product-specific API data into it's own page / URL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

This is my first time tackling this problem with React so please bear with me! I'd like to accomplish the following:

- When a user clicks on a product, it loads that product's link containing it's specific information (image, description, etc.)
- That URL would be something like 'myapp.com/product#/'

The API data is actually contained as a JSON in a local db.json file and has all the information for each product that I'd like to pull in. I'm using the Context API for managing the data.

Here's a [live demo](https://dazzling-brown-530cd5.netlify.app/) and the [full project code](https://codesandbox.io/s/nce-forked-jh4py?file=/src/App.js).

This is what I have so far:

```
export default function MachineCard({ image, title }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="col-lg-3">
        <div className="card">
          <Link to="/details"> <-- want this to link to product-specific page
            <img className="img-fluid" src={image} alt={title} />
            <div className="title">
              <h2>{title}</h2>
            </div>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react router there is an option to /:id this way and it'll pick it up and render the right product or page. I have forked your demo and I have added the solution check it out and let me know if it helped.
https://codesandbox.io/s/nce-forked-nizd5?file=/src/components/MachineCard.js

Also check this react router document it will help you a lot. https://reactrouter.com/web/example/url-params

Comment: Cool! So it totally works on the forked version. I pasted <Link to={`/details/${id}`}> into my local project in MachineCard.js, and also adjust my MachineDetail Route in Routes.js to <Route path="/details/:id" component={MachineDetail} />.

Having done that though, it's just showing a blank page when I click on any link on my local project but works as expected on your fork! Any idea why?

Comment: Your routes are defined in index.js files. Currently you're not using Routes.js anywhere. If you edit it in index.js file it should work. If this solution worked for you can you please mark it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks very much @Adi!